# Binary tree pruning

Tags: binary-tree

I am new to programming so please bear with me. I was solving this question https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/description/ and wrote down this solution:

```
TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
  if(root==nullptr)   
    return root;       
  pruneTree(root->left);   
  pruneTree(root->right);   
  if(root->val==0 && root->left==nullptr && root->right==nullptr) {  
    free(root); 
    return NULL;   
  }
  return root;            
}
```

but this returned me the same tree as original and the correct answer is as follows:

```
TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) { 
  if(root==nullptr)   
    return root;
  root->left=pruneTree(root->left);   
  root->right=pruneTree(root->right);   
  if(root->val==0 && root->left==nullptr && root->right==nullptr) {  
    free(root); 
    return NULL;   
  }
  return root;            
}
```

Can someone explain me the difference between two codes.

Comment: I think you need to learn how function parameters work and the difference between "in", "out" and "ref".  Or it may be you are not used to recersive code.

Comment: Also please used a tag to say what language the code is in.

Comment: Can you please me any good sources.

Answer (score -1):

You don't modify nodes while process the tree.

```
root->left=pruneTree(root->left);   
root->right=pruneTree(root->right);
```

VS your code

```
pruneTree(root->left);   
pruneTree(root->right);
```